# How to check pages' visits in a website

Tags: javascript, php, google-analytics, web-statistics

I 've created a website for a real estate agency, so there is a page for each property in this site. Finally, I would like to check how many visits every property gets, collect and display these stats somehow. Can this be done with Google Analytics or any other already developed solution or I have to do it increasing a visit counter for each page and storing it in my database(which might increase page load time)? I am using Symfony 2 if this can be a useful information anyhow.

Comment: Just use google analytics...

Comment: Google Analytics do keep record of number of visitors by page, so you use that.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Google Analytics can be used to store the number of visitors and all the data analytics like page views and the regions in which the page is being viewed and many more.